# How to run ranger from a script

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, xdotool

I'm writing a script which would allow me to open ranger FM in a certain shell profile. I managed to get it open in Xterm by adding `$SHELL` at the end of my script. What i want is for my script to open a terminal (i'm using konsole on manjaro) in a certain profile, write the word ranger and press Enter, so i end up with ranger FM in the terminal and profile of my choosing.

I have tried pipeing ranger command into konsole, but the command only opens konsole

`ranger | konsole`

i have also tried pipeing input commands into konsole, but that only outputs in Xterm and opens konsole.

`konsole | xdotool type ranger`

or

`xdotool type rager | konsole`

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/682850/open-new-konsole-from-script-executing-command-and-becoming-interactive-on-conc

Comment: Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in a previous question at:

https://superuser.com/questions/682850/open-new-konsole-from-script-executing-command-and-becoming-interactive-on-conc

The desired effect was achived with the command:

`konsole --profile profile_name -e /bin/bash ranger`

which, as i assume opens console and executes a bash command in the same command. No pipeing input into konsole was required.

konsole also allows to add a startup command in profile settings under:

`General --> Command
/bin/bash ranger`

This way you can call ranger directly from a profile

`konsole --profile profile_name`